# Multiple taps with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I have attached 3 tap gesture recognizers to the same view - single, double and triple tap. However, a double tap results in the single and double tap selector being called and the same for a triple tap. I expected that UITapGestureRecognizer class would have handled this situation appropriately. Does multiple tap gestures require additional code? Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ended up using only a single tap and a double tap. To get this to work properly, the following line should be added to the single gesture recognizer:

```
[singleTapGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapGR];
```